# chimney leak black liquid

Tags: leak, chimney

2 years ago I had my roof re shingled and chimney re grouted.  This year I noticed a black liquid leaking into my basement where my water heater is located. The water heater I know is vented out the chimney. 
There was alot of rain and snow this year.
Is it normal for water to get into chimney?
I want to know because my chimney is still under warranty, do I need to contact the contractor to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely normal for some water getting into a chimney with driven wind. Even with a wood stove that has a wind driven deflector on the stack those get some water but not as much as a conventional brick chimney. My dad had a chimney sweep company and we installed wood stoves in the 70’s like crazy. We also had to have training for inspections and it is not unusual for a driving rain or snow to enter the chimney and be noticed as a leak especially if the chimney is not hot from use.

Comment: Maybe, but the OP has stated that their roof was just reshingled and the chimney bricks repointed. Roofers do not always take care to respect chimney flashing, so who knows what’s going on up there? While it might be normal for some driven rain and snow to enter a chimney, it shouldn’t be assumed that that’s the cause of the water the OP is seeing. It’s also being suggested that seeing this water is a new issue, which might suggest a new problem. If the recent work is under warrantee, it should be looked at.

Comment: @paul , 2 years back and this year they have had heavy snow and rain so it was not a recent change.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal for water to get into a chimney. As a place to start you should contact the contractor if it is under warranty and have them look. It is very difficult to say without looking at the chimney and the situation itself to identify the possible cause of the water you are seeing. Chimneys are vulnerable in more than a few places, and the details of protecting these vulnerabilities are not always well executed... the flashing which keeps water from getting into the chimney/roof joint is one such detail, as is the chimney cap which keeps water from going straight down it. The mortar joints themselves can also permit water infiltration if in very bad shape. Have it checked out!

Comment: It is normal for some water to get to the inside a chimney, depending on the type and cap the amount can be enough to make quite a mess if the fireplace or wood stove is not being used. Ones that are in use evaporate the moisture before it gets to the lower areas.